# Let D, E, F be the feet of altitude from A, B, C in triangle ABC. Prove that the perpendicular bisector of ED also bisects BC.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Let $D, E, F$ be the feet of altitude from $A, B, C$ in $\triangle ABC$. Prove that the perpendicular bisector of $EF$ also bisects $BC$.

Source:Challenges and Thrills of Pre College Maths

What I did:I tried by angle chasing and sine rule but I failed

I guess it is entire question. Please tell me how to improve this question or consider reopening as this is one of causes of my ban.

Comment: Do you know the theorem about the midpoint of the right triangle which states that the point is equidistant from the vertices of the triangle?

Comment: What do you mean by mid point of right angle triangle?

Comment: I am sorry. I had in mind the midpoint of the hypotenuse in a right triangle.

Comment: Yes I do know it. It is true because mid point of hypotenuse is the circumcentre.

Comment: It is true not because of this. The relation is rather opposite. The question is if it is allowed to be used in the proof?

Comment: No I don't think so as we will get into circle geometry via this

Comment: If no proof that $ME=MF$ is allowed there is no hope to prove the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\angle CFB=\angle BEC=90°$

Therefore $FBCE$ is a cyclic quadrilateral with diameter $BC$.

We know that the line drawn from centre of a circle to centre of a chord in it is perpendicular bisector of the chord. Let $O$ be the centre of circle($BCEF$). Perpendicular bisector from $EF$ will cross through $O$.

As proved above $BC$ is the diameter of circle($BCEF$) that means $O$ lies on it and is its midpoint. Hence the statement is true.